# Работа с WebSocket через .NET

Tags: c#, websocket

Не организовывал ли кто-нибудь обмен данными через WebSocket?
Сложность и непонятность заключается в том, что при тестировании моей реализации, когда я тестирую работу на localhost работа происходит корректно:
создается webSocket и происходит ожидание сообщения от подключенного пользователя.

А когда я заливаю на рабочий сервак, то при подключении к WebSocket-у почему-то помимо простого подключения происходит еще и отправка некоторого количества данных со страницы, которая подключается.
Не могу понять, почему на локальной моей машине работает по одному, а на рабочем сервере по другому.

Разница состоит только в ip-адресе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почитайте [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/hh975342.aspx). На локальной машине у вас и сервер. и клиент имеют одинаковые IP-адреса, соответственнол упрощается соединение. Отсюда и дополнительные данные.